# jQuery: Replace each Background-Image with <img> tags leaving sources unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, background-image

How would I replace every background image with the class name:

> backgroundPNGAcontain

with a div (class name imgWrapper) and image having the same url source?

I'm very close. This is my code:

```
$( ".backgroundPNGAcontain" ).html( "<div class='imgWrapper'><img></div>" );

$( ".backgroundPNGAcontain" ).each(function() {
  var url = $( this ).css('background-image');
  url = url.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');
  $(".imgWrapper>img").attr("src", url);
  $( this ).css( "background-image", "none" );
});
```

---

It's just that `$(".imgWrapper>img").attr("src", url);` doesn't change the source by matching every image correctly, instead it finds the last background image and sets every image to that.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gd29wLu5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.imgeWrapper').find('img').attr('src','/url');
```

Comment: I recently added a fiddle... I also tried replacing that one line of code with this and the images didn't show up. https://jsfiddle.net/gd29wLu5/2/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it such that others can learn from it

Comment: At one point, there was an "e" before "wrapper", as "imgeWrapper" instead of "imgWrapper".  Also, changing the first class selector to a this selector fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is replacing all images under imgWrapper with the same attribute.
Instead of `$(".imgWrapper>img").attr("src", url);` 
try `$(this).children("img").attr("src",url);`

Comment: I recently added a fiddle... I tried replacing that one line of code and the images didn't show up. https://jsfiddle.net/gd29wLu5/1/

Comment: I have edited the answer. Just remove the last line from your js of jsfiddle.

Comment: Removing the last snip of code causes the img tags to be blank, and leaves the background images there.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped contribute to my edit of Tajammul Ghafoor's answer.